# UdpClient syntax FromAsync

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

quite new to c# and tasks... Trying to find the correct syntax to wrap UDPclient into FromAsync(...), seems I miss some parameters...(can't use ReceiveAsync as it should work with 
.NET 4.0)

```
public Task<byte[]> GetUDPmessageAsync()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[100];
    myUdpClient = new UdpClient(12000);

    Task<byte[]> task = Task<byte[]>.Factory.FromAsync(myUdpClient.BeginReceive, myUdpClient.EndReceive,?,?);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use `FromAsync` since `UdpClient.EndReceive` take a ref parameter, which makes it incompatible with all the overloads of `FromAsync`. You can make your own extension method though:

```
public static Task<byte[]> ReceiveAsync(this UdpClient client, IPEndPoint endpoint)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<byte[]> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
    AsyncCallback callback = ar => {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = client.EndReceive(ar, ref endpoint);
            tcs.SetResult(bytes);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    };
    client.BeginReceive(callback, null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is working great. I see that UDP datagram messages are buffered in a way. When I call this method once, hold execution and call the method some time later again, it will return immediately with those messages received in the mean time one by one.  Suppose I should close the client and create a new one everytime. Anyway, my initial problem is solved, I can move one...